# Magento 2 Captcha image is not loading why?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

when i click on the forget password in my Magento it is asking for enter email and captcha but captcha image is not loading. why its happening and which files are responsible for that ?
Thanks..

Comment: have you check console? Is there any error there?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () - this is the error i got sir

Comment: Now try to resolve that error, that is the reason why captcha not loaded. Confirm you configured it properly from admin?

Comment: sir may i know what are the reasons for that error

Comment: please check the configuration from the admin.